# Apache Listening Port

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I need some help. I'm trying to set up a web interface for a cloud system and I have used this conf (provided by the vendor)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sxweb.foo.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sxweb/public/
    <Directory /var/www/sxweb/public>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.skylable.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.skylable.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I try to open the page, the web interface is not displayed (I have a message from that says to install the web interface)

I asked support to the vendor (is an open source) and that is its answer

> On which IPort is Apache listening?
>
> On which IPort is SX listening?
>
> You cannot run SX Server and Apache on the same IPort.

Now, from my little experience in Apache (I admit it, I know very few things) Apache gives the "platform" where the software run and it should point against the SSL or HTTP port.

Can someone help me to understand how it works and what it means?

Comment: Try to execute `netstat -ntlp` on the computer where you're trying to run Apache. This will tell you what process (if any) is listening for connections on TCP port 443.

Answer (score 0):

- from the config above it looks like you are configuring a HTTP**S** virtual host so please ensure that in the browser you specify http**s**://sxweb.foo.com
- in the same time what they are telling you is that you can not run the skylable server on the same machine where you run your apache server as the skylable it needs port 443 and 8443 for it's normal communications (skylable is not a website / webapp that you can run inside apache)
- you can either install the apache on a new machine, or make it listen to a new IP address or port other then the skylable server